# elastic search sort after aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an elastic search query showing distinct value for [Have CVID], for each CONTACT_ID, and I want to sort by [Have CVID] count after aggregation. Where can I add the sort by here?

```
POST /dashboard/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
       {
          "match": {
            "Have CVID": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
        "CVID": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "CONTACT_ID.keyword"
          },
      "aggs": {
        "type_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "Have CVID.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
   }}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `order` to your `terms` aggregation and specify a sub-aggregation to order by, like this:

```
POST /dashboard/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [{
        "match": {
          "Have CVID": ""
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "CVID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CONTACT_ID.keyword",
        "order": {
          "type_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "type_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "Have CVID.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ElasticSearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order)

Comment: thanks @Milen Georgiev, I got this error though: type" : "json_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput);

Comment: @ella , sorry - there was a bad formatting in the JSON. I've edited the answer to fix it, can you try again?